# attach document in email

Tags: email, onedrive, blu-win-hd, attachments

I'm using Google Email on BLU Win HD LTE. I want to attach document from Overdrive to email message.

But when I press "attachment" button I see only images on Overdrive. Although I can see all documents when I just press Overdrive button on screen.

How I can attach document?

Answer (score 1):

The email app only supports browsing for pictures; The OneDrive app supports creating a "sharing" link to send to a recipient.

If you open the document in the relevant app (such as Word), you may be able to choose to share it via email there (At least Word supports approach)

Comment: okay, I open document in Word and have option Share and can choose Google mail. It create new email with attachment. But if I have email from somebody and need to reply with my resume, how I can do this?